# Integrate Blazor into existing ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-6.0

I am integrating server-side Blazor components in an existing and big ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project.

I followed the configuration steps from the official MS docs such as:

```
services.AddServerSideBlazor();
services.AddRazorPages();
endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
```

...in the `Startup.cs` file.

Till now, we did not experience any problems.

Our current implementation is that we show a specific controller view filled with a Blazor component.

From this (first) component that is shown, a user can navigate to a second component, but staying in the same view. Internally, we use `NavigationManager` class from the first component to navigate to another. And as you know we need to specify the URL of other components with the `@page` attribute, because `NavigationManager` navigates with the URLs specified in `@page`.

So, right now when I open this view (which has blazor components), the URL looks like this -> `myapp.com/Example`. And as I said from the component in this view we navigate to  `myapp.com/Example/Details` - the view stays the same, the components inside are changed and so is the URL.

The problem is that when we switch to the next (or subsequent) components, which changes the URL, we lose connection to the Blazor Hub. This was found because OnAfterRenderAsync does not work, for subsequent components with different URLs (although the component is rendered and OnInitializedAsync still works, not sure how is it possible).

After debugging and reading - as a mistake, we did not include the tag `<base href="~/" />` in the _Layout when we did the initial Blazor configuration. I included it, but found out that it changes how the relative paths are resolved.
For example I have numerous scripts like this:   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/gov-icons.css?v=1.0.0" />` which already start with tilda (~).

From testing, I've found out that for example this script (in _Layout):

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        })
    </script>
```

stopped working.

Also I've read several documentations with the same problem. For example here:
[MS Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43191)

They explain that the MapBlazorHub() - we should pass a path to it.
I also looked at this Github:

[Blazor - MVC integration](https://github.com/kinetiq/Blazor.WithMVC)

And here they also pass new path, but it is used on a brand new ASP.NET MVC Project. And I am using existing big project. So it is not very clear for me, whether I should change the scripts or not.

My question is - when I add `<base href="~/Blazor/" />` in the _Layout file, should I expect any issues with scripts, css references etc. ?
And if so - how to tackle this issue? Because the plan is to use Blazor components in this MVC app.